# Import FBX file - Issues with rotation calculation

Tags: c++, rotation, maya, matrix-multiplication, fbx

I am currently writing a plugin to import fbx files into maya (I know there is already a plugin existing but I need to use it in my plugin).
For a given joint, I have a pre-rotation, a rotation and a post-rotation.
If I multiply all 3, the result is not the same than Maya is having when using the standard fbx import.
Example:

```
// Pre-Rotation:-90 x 15.5044 x 90
// Rotation:-8.54572 x 1.07966 x -46.245
// Post-Rotation:90 x -15.5044 x -90

//    Maya standard FBX result (correct) -> -2.106 x 8.814 x 88.132
//    My result (error) -> 23.89 x 40.8658 x 17.0975
```

I am using the standard MEulerRotation multiplication in Maya's API, but this doesn't seem to do the trick. What calculation could lead me to Maya's result ?

This is my piece of code:

```
MEulerRotation prerot(-90 , 15.5044 , 90);
MEulerRotation rotation(-8.54572 , 1.07966 , -46.245);
MEulerRotation postrot(90 , -15.5044 , -90);
rotFinal=prerot*rotation*postrot;

MFnTransform t3(myJointObject);
MQuaternion q;
q=rotFinal;
t3.setRotation(q); // -> The result is different than the standard fbximport.
```

Comment: Does your definition of your coordinate system match that of Maya's? Do you need to account for different scaling factors? Are you constructing the headers of the FBX file appropriately for the proper version? Is your data alignment in your FBX file correct? There are so many questions that can be asked to try to answer your question with the little bit of information that you have provided. Also which OS, Compiler and IDE are you using?

Comment: Another thing to take careful consideration of is the order in which you are applying matrix multiplications for your MVPM (Model View Projection Matrix). Order does matter since many matrix multiplications have no inverse.

Comment: Another thing to be careful of when using Euler Rotations in 3 Dimensions is the high possibility of Gimbal Lock! Be Aware of this when rotating an object across more than one axis in 3D. To avoid Gimbal Lock a better and more efficient solution is to use Quaternions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Francis. I am reading an existing FBX (that Maya can open properly using the standard fbx import tool), create the associated joints hierarchy, and translate + rotate the joints as indicated in the FBX using the MFnTransform command (question edited with more code).

Comment: No problem at all, I've had some experience with FBX files, however I was doing the reverse. I was taking an FBX file from either Maya or 3DS Max and reading in the data and stripping out what I needed into my own parser for my own application. I'm okay with code and getting better, but I understand a majority of the concepts and the math behind it. So if I feel that I can help in any way even if I'm wrong but leads someone to a possible solution to their problem then that is all that matters. It is a continuous learning process and every bit of help helps.

Comment: I found out that there is a local_rotation property for each joint. Should this one be included in the Quaternion multiplication, and if yes where between pre-rot and post-rot ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure but I'm sure you should be able to find some documentation on Maya and these attributes on youtube. This may help you get started. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Maya+local_rotation